# MySQL Invalid TIME format

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the TIME data type for storing the employee extra hours worked, in that some instances the time value is stored as like this format

```
9.08:00:00, 
2.16:00:00, 
1.00:00:00, 
-9.05:00:00
```

what is this format and how i know the exact value of this ?

please help on this

thanks in advance,

shiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9.08:00:00 
 here 9 is the 9 days then 9*24=216 and .08  is the 8 hours, so totally 216+5=221 hours

2.16:00:00 same as above 2 - 2 days 2*24 and 16 is 16 hours 48+16=64

to see the above calculation by using the MySQL function

Note: in Mysql 5.5.18 the TIME data type column stores the time value like this ...

Answer (score 0):

You need convert it to string with TIME_FORMAT(). (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(time_field, '%H:%i') FROM table
```

%H:$i its hours:minutes

Comment: 9.08:00:00 
 here 9 is the 9 days then 9*24=216 and .08  is the 8 hours, so totally 216+5=221 hours

2.16:00:00 same as above 2 - 2 days 2*24 and 16 is 16 hours 48+16=64

to see the above calculation by using the SELECT TIME_FORMAT(time_field, '%H:%i') FROM user_table;

Note: in Mysql 5.5.18 the TIME data type column stores the time value like this ...